# AspNet WeApi 2, Autofac

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, зависимости, внедрение

Я использую обобщённый интерфейс

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T :class
                        {
                            List<T> GetAllRecords();
                        }
```

Так же реализую обобщённый репозиторий

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
                        {
                            protected readonly DataContext context;
                            public BaseRepository(DataContext data)
                            {
                                context = data;
                            }

                            public List<T> GetAllRecords()
                            {
                                return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
                            }
                        }
```

DataContext - контекст БД.

Создал интерфейс, который будет расширять базовый интерфейс

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
                        {
                            void MyMethod();
                        }

public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUserRepository
                        {
                            protected readonly DataContext context;
                            protected readonly IUserRepository repository;
                            public UserRepository(DataContext data, IUserRepository user):base (data)
                            {
                                context = data;
                                repository = user;

                            }

                            public void MyMethod()
                            {
                                throw new NotImplementedException();
                            }
```

Файл конфигурации Autofac

```
                         public class AutofacRegister
                    {
                        public static void ConfigureContainer()
                        {

                            // получаем экземпляр контейнера
                            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

                            // Register your Web API controllers.

                            // builder.RegisterType<DataContext>();
                            builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
                            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
                            var container = builder.Build();
                            var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

                            // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
                            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
                        }
                    }
```

В GlobalAsax добавил строчку кода

```
AutofacRegister.ConfigureContainer();
```

В контроллере.

```
public class UserController : ApiController
                    {
                        IUserRepository repository;

                        public UserController(IUserRepository user)
                        {
                            repository = user;
                        }

                        public List<User> GetRecords()
                        {
                            return repository.GetAllRecords();
                        }
                    }
```

Выдаёт ошибку при обращении к методу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём ошибка, разбираюсь с внедрением зависимостей, но никак не поддаётся. Что не так делаю, при работе с обобщёнными репозиториями?

Comment: Ваш  UserRepository наследует  IUserRepository. Можно спросить зачем Вы передаете IUserRepository в конструкторе?

Comment: Моя ошибка, тут ведь просто наследуемся от интерфейса и переопределяем метод, видимо я с примера взял, и не понял сам для чего это. Изменил конст-р public UserRepository(DataContext data):base(data)
        {
            context = data;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разкоментируйте строке

```
          // builder.RegisterType<DataContext>();
```

Autofac ничего не знает про Ваш DataContext при создании `UserRepository` в

```
 public UserRepository(DataContext data, IUserRepository user):base (data)
```

Comment: Спасибо, раскоментировал builder.RegisterType<DataContext>(), ошибка ушла, данные из БД загрузились.

Comment: Данные из БД не должны подгружаться, иначе теряется смысл в использовании Autofac. Я надеюсь, что Autofac просто создал Вам фейковый DataContext, не подгружая данные из БД

Comment: я имею ввиду, что при обращении к методу контроллера, не отображается сообщение "An error occured when trying to create controller UserController", а конкретно отрабатывает метод  GetRecords() в контроллере, извиняюсь, выше некорректно написал